# Condition for intersection of two 3D lines.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

Given two lines below and that $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are non complanar , find condition so that they intersect, furthermore find intersection point.

$$\vec{r_1} = \vec{a}+k(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})\\
\vec{r_2}=\vec{b}+l(\vec{c}\times \vec{a})$$

Here $\vec{a},\vec{b} $ are position vectors of two points on lines.

---

**Trial 1**

I try to manipulate but think I went wrong, I rearranged to get:

$$\vec{a}-\vec{b} = \vec{c}\times (l\vec{a}+k\vec{b})$$

Now this is never possible because left side is always in common plane of $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ and right side is always out of it.

I am wrong, obvious, **but what is my mistake.**

**Trial 2**

The lines only intersect is they are complanar, so

$$(\vec{b}-\vec{a}) \cdot ((\vec{b}\times\vec{c})\times(\vec{c}\times\vec{a}))=0\\
(\vec{b}-\vec{a})\cdot(((\vec{b}\times\vec{c})\cdot \vec{a}) \vec{c})=0$$

instantly giving $\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}$, which should be the condition.. I am not concerned with this, but if it contains mistake, please point.

Comment: why trial 1 should be wrong?

Comment: @jack how did you find that without calculation

Comment: Also why its closed?

Comment: @KingTut: by definition, $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ is a vector which is orthogonal to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, so by drawing a couple of diagrams it is not difficult to figure what is the intersection of the given lines. About the reason for closing, I am not aware of it, and I believe there is enough context, so I am casting a reopening vote.

Comment: Thanks a lot jack d'aurizio, I will try to work on your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you found in the first attempt is not wrong. It means that $a-b$ is perpendicular to $c$ and perpendicular to $(la+kb)$.

Bear in mind that $a-b$ and $(la+kb)$ are co-planar, but could be mutually perpendicular for the correct choice of $k,l$.

If you do the dot product of the equation in Trial 1 with either $a$ or $b$ you can obtain $k$ or $l$ respectively, so the intersection point can be written as $$r=a+\left(\frac{a\cdot b-b^2}{b\cdot c\times a}\right)b\times c$$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Following the first trial

$$\vec{r_1} =\vec{r_2}\iff \vec{a}-\vec{b} = \vec{c}\times (l\vec{a}+k\vec{b})
$$

which is possible when $\vec c$ is orthogonal both to $\vec{a}$ and to $\vec{b}$, thus we can assume $\vec c=t\,(\vec a\times \vec b)$.

Comment: Thanks gimusi, I missed this possibility